# .Net error : Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, devart

I decide to post my question here after many unsucessful research.

I have an error on my application when i generate a report. I didn't have the problem when i'm debugging on visual studio but when i deploy on my server (windows server 2012) i have this error:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory

This error appear in a column in an Excel report.

I can see in eventviewer this message : ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0

> An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated.
>
> Application ID: /LM/W3SVC/5/ROOT
>
> Process ID: 836
>
> Exception: System.AccessViolationException
>
> Message: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is corrupt.
>
> StackTrace:    at OciDynamicType.nativeOCIHandleFree(HandleRef , Int32
>   )    at OciDynamicType.OCIHandleFree(HandleRef , Int32 )    at
>   Devart.Data.Oracle.a9.a()    at
>   Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleDataReader.Close()    at
>   Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleDataReader.Finalize()

I have tried to :

- Disabling JIT
- Disabling compiler optimizations
- Commenting out all loaded assemblies

I can't explain where in the code this error append, this error occurs randomly but alway at the same place.

Sorry for my english, i'm french :)

Comment: do you have debug or release build on the server? if debug, try with release build, if release, try with debug build too

Comment: On the server i have a release build, i will try debug build

Comment: I have the same error with a debug build :/

Comment: This exception if often caused when data reader accessed from multiple threads.

Comment: It seems to come from a Finalize call, which means that it is trying to destroy an already destroyed instance, which _can_ mean some concurrency issues.